# How to Add a new Name Value Pair to an Incoming Request's Headers in ServiceStack 5.0?

Tags: servicestack

I have a custom Plugin I wrote which I add to the Plugins list inside the Configure method of AppHost.

I'm using this plugin to authenticate the internal users that came through Postman. Get their credentials, authenticate them and create a token for them. I want to add this token to the request header.

This used to work with ServiceStack 4.0 but with 5.0 the implementation of INameValueCollection which allowed this has been deprecated and replaced with c#'s NameValueCollection. But NameValueCollection doesn't allow you to add anything unless you create a new NameValueCollection object (It throws an error that says "specified method is not supported") but Headers in IRequest doesn't have a setter, so I can't do that either.

Is there a reason why the ability to add something to an incoming request header was removed? Is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying the incoming Request Headers which are immutable in most Hosts where it also manifests in ServiceStack's light weight abstractions. Use `IRequest.Items` dictionary for any metadata you want to attach to the Request which is available to all Filters/Services/etc throughout [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](http://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations).

Comment: How do I ensure the request will have the correct Authorization then since NetCoreRequest.cs gets it from the Header? `public string Authorization => request.Headers[HttpHeaders.Authorization];`

Comment: @val Sounds like this should've been a Custom Auth Provider, but you can authenticate a user by [populating its Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#overriding-a-user-session) in `IRequest.Items`.